# How to pass ENUM as function argument in C

Tags: c, function, enums

I have an enum declared as:

```
typedef enum 
{
   NORMAL = 0,           
   EXTENDED              

} CyclicPrefixType_t;

CyclicPrefixType_t cpType;
```

I need a function that takes this as an argument:

```
fun(CyclicPrefixType_t cpType);
```

The function declaration is:

```
void fun(CyclicPrefixType_t cpType);
```

How can I fix it? I don't think it is correct.

Comment: Why do you think that is incorrect?  What did your compiler tell you?

Comment: Looks just fine to me; have you tried compiling it?

Comment: Don't use typenames with `_t` at the end these are usually reserved, in particular by POSIX. But as the others say, your prototype is ok.

Answer (score 50):

That's pretty much *exactly* how you do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    NORMAL = 31414,
    EXTENDED
} CyclicPrefixType_t;

void func (CyclicPrefixType_t x) {
    printf ("%d\n", x);
}

int main (void) {
    CyclicPrefixType_t cpType = EXTENDED;
    func (cpType);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs the value of `EXTENDED` (31415 in this case) as expected.

Answer (score 15):

The following also works, FWIW (which confuses slightly...)

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum CyclicPrefixType_t {
    NORMAL = 31414,
    EXTENDED
};

void func (enum CyclicPrefixType_t x) {
    printf ("%d\n", x);
}

int main (void) {
    enum CyclicPrefixType_t cpType = EXTENDED;
    func (cpType);
    return 0;
}
```

Apparently it's a [legacy C thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/385023/32453).

Comment: In this example, `CyclicPrefixType_t` is not actuaslly a type but just the name of the `enum` - so it's a bit different.

Comment: if I pass a value which is not in the enum list also received by ' void func ()` and the same value is printed. is it valid behavior ?

Comment: Maybe if 2 enums have the same value?  Wouldn't be common... :)