# Is this redundant "typedef" strictly legal?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14, c++03

I found the following declaration in v0.9.2 of the ACE Radius library:

```
// Types of attribute data
typedef enum AttributeFormat_e
{
    E_ATTR_FORMAT_INTEGER,
    E_ATTR_FORMAT_IP_ADDRESS,
    E_ATTR_FORMAT_STRING,
    E_ATTR_FORMAT_VENDOR_SPECIFIC,
    E_ATTR_FORMAT_USER_PASSWORD,
    E_ATTR_FORMAT_CHAP_PASSWORD
};
```

That leading `typedef` is completely meaningless and should not be present.
Indeed, GCC emits the following diagnostic:

> /usr/include/ace-radius/RadiusAttribute.h:597: warning: ‘typedef’ was ignored in this declaration

Now, this is ultimately harmless, despite being a bizarre sort of half-meaningful half-C declaration in a file that otherwise may only be parsed as C++ (the declaration is found as a `private` member in a `class`).

But purely out of curiosity I wanted to know whether this is strictly compliant, or strictly ill-formed, and couldn't quite tell from the standard.

Is this leading `typedef` legal? Or is GCC being permissive?

Comment: `C` Backward Compatibility.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do you use typedef when declaring an enum in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385023/why-do-you-use-typedef-when-declaring-an-enum-in-c)

Comment: @al-Acme: No, look more closely. This is not `typedef enum E {} name;` ... this is `typedef enum E {};`

Comment: This doesn't seem like a duplicate to me, the OP seems to know about the implications of `typedef enum` in C.

Comment: Also it's "C" not "`C`".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's legal, for the simple reason that there's no rule against it anywhere in the standard. The effect of `typedef` is only defined as what effect it has on names defined with the `typedef` specifier, so when there are no names defined with that specifier, the behaviour is well-defined: `typedef` simply has no effect.

The grammar in general does not require any declarators for a *simple-declaration*, and you probably already know this, since you would not have been surprised to see `enum AttributeFormat_e { ... };` without the `typedef`. The productions are

> *simple-declaration*:
>       *decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* *init-declarator-list<sub>opt</sub>* `;`
>       *attribute-specifier-seq* *decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* *init-declarator-list* `;`

As long as no *attribute-specifier-seq* is present in a *simple-declaration*, the *init-declarator-list* is optional.

`typedef int;` would be invalid, as would `int;` without the `typedef`, but that's a different rule: the rule there is that a declaration has to declare something. That rule doesn't apply to what's in your question, because that declaration does declare something. More precisely, C++11 [dcl.dcl]p3:

> In a *simple-declaration*, the optional *init-declarator-list* can be omitted only when declaring a class (Clause 9) or enumeration (7.2), that is, when the *decl-specifier-seq* contains either a *class-specifier*, an *elaborated-type-specifier* with a *class-key* (9.1), or an *enum-specifier*. [...]

The code in the question is declaring an enumeration, so this rule is not violated.

`static enum E { x };` would be invalid, but that's another different rule: C++11 [dcl.stc]p1:

> [...] If a *storage-class-specifier* appears in a *decl-specifier-seq*, there can be no `typedef` specifier in the same *decl-specifier-seq* and the *init-declarator-list* of the declaration shall not be empty (except for an anonymous union declared in a named namespace or in the global namespace, which shall be declared `static` (9.5)). [...]

`const enum E { x };` would also be invalid, but that's a third different rule: C++11 [dcl.type.cv]p1:

> [...] If a *cv-qualifier* appears in a *decl-specifier-seq*, the *init-declarator-list* of the declaration shall not be empty. [...]

There is simply no such rule anywhere for `typedef`.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good argument. The standard is not "anything is legal as long as it's not made illegal", and you haven't pointed out the feature of `typedef` (or the fact of its grammar production) that allows the "target name" to be emitted. I'm looking for something a bit more concrete than "it's just legal, mmkay?"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You already know very well that the grammar allows declarations without any declarators. That's how `enum AttributeFormat_e { ... };` without the `typedef` would be valid. But I will elaborate a bit.

Comment: Can you tell us which grammar productions cover this? Your answer is still "there's nothing to ban it" well great but _something_ defines it, even if passively.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure, edited. Does that cover it?

Comment: Aha! Yes, I think that probably does. It's still not very satisfying but that's C++'s fault, not yours. Thanks for your time

Comment: I had to make a C++ parser to extract some `typedef struct tag {...} NAME, *PNAME;` declarations. I based my parser rules on those of the old lex/yacc C grammar. I was very baffled by  the rule in regard with "typedef": `storage_class_spec : 'auto' | 'register' | 'static' | 'extern' | 'typedef'`. Yeah, you can have several typedef! mixed with the others! I wonder if that weird rule is still the same for c++ grammar?

Comment: @hlide Neither C nor C++ allows `typedef` to be mixed with (other) storage class specifiers. The grammar allows it, but the semantics don't. C says "At most, one storage-class specifier may be given in the declaration specifiers in a declaration." And in C++, `typedef` is not a storage class specifier, and the rule is written as "The typedef specifier shall not be combined in a decl-specifier-seq with any other kind of specifier except a type-specifier." Note: `typedef` *can* appear along with `extern` if the latter is part of a linkage-specification: `extern "C" typedef void f();` is valid.

Comment: @hvd Good to hear. The fact is you cannot trust a free-context C/C++ grammar parsing to validate source or detect ill-constructed declaration.